# Classictext: remove comma in citation of antique texts

Tags: biblatex

I want to quote some ancient sources, but I do not know how to remove the comma between the name of an author/text and the following chapter number. Actually, this is what I get: PALL. V. CHRYS., 1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq). However, I want to remove the comma between "CHRYS." and "1". Therefore, it should be: PALL. V. CHRYS. 1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq). Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Pall.SC,
    title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
    editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
    series = {SC},
    number = {341–342},
    volumes = {2},
    location = {Paris},
    keywords = {Vita},
    date = {1988},
  }
  @classictext{Pallad.Dial,
    author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
    xref = {Pall.SC}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see this comma is just the normal `postnotedelim`. Do you want to remove it also for other kinds of sources? Do you want to remove the comma only in specific circumstances for classical sources or in all situations? (In this case I gather that the first "1" is a chapter number and "1-5" a further designation. What if you have no chapter number for another source?)

Comment: Thanks!. No, I want remove the comma only for classical sources.

Answer (score 1):

Since your classics text uses the dedicated entry type `classictext`, we can just test for that in our definition of `postnotdelim`

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{%
  \ifentrytype{classictext}
    {\addspace}
    {\addcomma\space}%
}
```

[image: Vgl.: Pall. v. Chrys. 1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq).]